# How to assign rating to specific picture?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "";

    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
    echo "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";
        echo "<img class='photoDeGallery' src='image/".$row['image']."'>";
       
             echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
                 echo "<span>Details</span> ";

                     echo "<div class='dropdown-content'>";
                         echo "<p>".$row['text']."</p>";
                     echo "</div>";

             echo "</div>";
        
             echo "<div class='feedback'>";

             echo "<input type='radio' name='star' id='loveIt' checked='checked'>";
             echo "<label for='loveIt'>";
             echo "<img class='imag' src='love_it.png'>";
             echo "<h4>love it</h4>";
             echo "</label>";

             echo "<input type='radio' name='star' id='likeIt'>";
             echo "<label for='likeIt'>";
             echo "<img class='imag' src='liked_it.png'>";
             echo "<h4>like it</h4>";
             echo "</label>";

             echo "<input type='radio' name='star' id='applause'>";
             echo "<label for='applause'>";
             echo "<img class='imag' src='applause.png'>";
             echo "<h4>applaus</h4>";
             echo "</label>";

             echo "<input type='radio' name='star' id='laugh'>";
             echo "<label for='laugh'>";
             echo "<img class='imag' src='laugh.png'>";
             echo "<h4>laugh</h4>";
             echo "</label>";

             echo "<input type='radio' name='star' id='boring'>";
             echo "<label for='boring'>";
             echo "<img class='imag' src='boring.png'>";
             echo "<h4>boring</h4>";
             echo "</label>";
             

                 

             echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";
}
```

Hallo, I provided the code above.

On a button_click runs the code above. The code inserts pictures on database and shows them on the website. Under each photo inside an img_div also been shown the "details" to the pic as well as rating. The rating-system I created using radio input (as it is to see in the code). The rating-system appears under every picture, which has been uploaded to the database and shown on the website.

The problem is:
when I rate a picture, all other pictures get the same rating.

How can i keep for each picture the own rating, so that rating been assigned 1:1 rating1:photo1, rating2:photo2 etc. ?

Should I store rating_clicks in a database or is there away to count the rates (likes, dislikes etc)?

I will be grateful if someone could help me and Modos wouldn't close my thread?
Best regards
Reda

Answer (score 0):

Your radio groups need the same name, but each group needs it's own unique shared name. You can do this by appending the ID of the item in with the name. That way when you sort out the POST data you'll have a reference to the ID that goes with the rating. Also you shouldn't be using the same IDs for multiple elements, so I changed those to data-attributes. You can wrap the text and radio in the label tag to associate the two together

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ? >

    <div id='img_div'>
<i class ='fas fa-times'></i>
<img class='photoDeGallery' src='image/<?php echo $row['image']?>'>
     <div class='dropdown'>
         <span>Details</span> 
             <div class='dropdown-content'>
                 <p><?php echo $row['text']?></p>
             </div>
     </div>

     <div class='feedback'>

    <label>
     <input type='radio' name='star_<?php echo $row['id']?>' data-reaction='loveIt' checked='checked'>
     <img class='imag' src='love_it.png'>
     <h4>love it</h4>
     </label>

    <label>
     <input type='radio' name='star_<?php echo $row['id']?>' data-reaction='likeIt'>
     <img class='imag' src='liked_it.png'>
     <h4>like it</h4>
     </label>

    <label>
     <input type='radio' name='star_<?php echo $row['id']?>' data-reaction='applause'>
     <img class='imag' src='applause.png'>
     <h4>applaus</h4>
     </label>

    <label>
     <input type='radio' name='star_<?php echo $row['id']?>' data-reaction='laugh'>
     <img class='imag' src='laugh.png'>
     <h4>laugh</h4>
     </label>

    <label>
     <input type='radio' name='star_<?php echo $row['id']?>' data-reaction='boring'>
     <img class='imag' src='boring.png'>
     <h4>boring</h4>
     </label>
     </div>
```

Then in your $_POST you can find your ratings like this

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $p => $v) {
  if (strpos($p, 'star_')!== false) { // if the name of the $_POST item has the string 'star_' in it
    $imgid = explode('_', $p)[1]; // get the id by exploding the name into an array like ['star','7'] and choosing the [1] index
    $rating = $v; // the rating itself will just be the $_POST value
  }
}?>
```

Comment: Hello Kinglish, thank you so much, I started yesterday another project, when i'm done with it, i will fix the problem with the rating-system trying your solution.
best regards
Reda

Comment: unfortunately i don't understand the code in the Post. I'll be so grateful, if you would please explain more

Comment: oh thank you very much ^^, so I should create a table in db for the rating-imgs and use then the $imgid for exploding. I'll try it, thank you again many times

Comment: you're welcome. if this helped solve your question, consider accepting it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Hello Kinglish, i'll do, thank you for the advise  :))

Comment: @Reda - thanks. Accepting a solution helps the site, helps me and helps others who some here looking for solutions. Go ahead and click that checkmark and let me know if you need anything else.